# I can't install ANY Microsoft Visual C++ packages after deleted "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache"

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio

I can't install ANY Microsoft Visual C++ packages after deleted "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache"!

The installer `.exe`

[image]

Error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What should I do? Is re-install Windows 10 the only option?

Comment: Have you uninstalled the previous versions, is there a reason, you deleted a required system directory?

Comment: @Ramhound This direcotry toke a few GB. By the way, I solved this problem by downloaded the exactly version of the missing package which cost me hours..

Answer (score 1):

Use the troubleshooter given in the Microsoft website:
[Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d)

Uninstall the problematic packages using this tool and then reinstall them using the installer downloadable from the Microsoft website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).